# A relation "table_name" does not exist in "Many2many relation" in Odoo 10.0

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

I want to do a functionality :"a student can inscript a course, or a teacher can choose a course to teach".
Here is my python code:
[image: Class SinhVien (student)]

[image: Class KhoaHoc(course)]

[image: Class GiaoVien (Teacher)]

[image: Class PhongHoc (classroom)]

Running odoo : A teacher want to choose a course to teach 
[image: He/she has to fill the name and the ID, and click "Add an item" below to select a course]

[image: Selecting a course]

[image]
[image: Click blue button "save" above, and it causes an error]

I don't know clearly why relation "lop_phu_trach" does not exist even though I initialized it in the model "studentmanagement.khoahoc"

Thanks for your help in advanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolved it, in model "studentmanagement.giaovien", I change to

```
LopPhuTrach = fields.Many2many('studentmanagement.khoahoc', string="Chọn lớp")
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have `lop_phu_trach` in your `studentmanagement.khoahoc` model. What you have is `LopPhuTrach`.

Try changing `lop_phu_trach` to `LopPhuTrach`.

Comment: It does not work. I've found in the "Many2Many Relation" in tab "settings" odoo that the relation LopPhuTrach belongs to "studentmanagement.giaovien", not "studentmanagement.khoahoc" ! So I don't know how to deal with it. I'm just an Odoo beginner!

Comment: The problem is that, I am a teacher, and I'd like to select a course at my model "studentmanagement.giaovien", not "studentmanagement.khoahoc". Unfortunately, relation "LopPhuTrach" just belongs to model  "studentmanagement.giaovien" only !

Comment: I've resolved it, in model "studentmanagement.giaovien", I change to "LopPhuTrach = fields.Many2many('studentmanagement.khoahoc', string="Chọn lớp")"